# How to use access token from google calendar in js

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

I have question regarding google calendar, and hope you can help me.

I have access_token from google calendar and that `access_token` was stored in `localStorage`.

```
          const googleAccessToken = e.vc.access_token;
          localStorage.setItem('googleAccessToken', googleAccessToken);
```

Now please help me understand how can I use this to avoid authorization every time.

For example I want to delete all events, And for that I wrote this code, and this code every time wants from me authorization:

```
   const handleDisconnect = () => {
    gapi.load('client:auth2', () => {
      console.log('loaded client');

      gapi.client.init({
        apiKey: API_KEY,
        clientId: CLIENT_ID,
        discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
        scope: SCOPES_CLEAR,
      });
      gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', () => {
        console.log('sdsd');
      });
      gapi.auth2
        .getAuthInstance()
        .signIn()
        .then(() => {
          var events = bb;
          var makeRequest = resource => {
            console.log(resource);

            var request = gapi.client.calendar.calendars.clear({
              calendarId: 'primary',
            });

            request.execute(resp => {
              console.log(resp);
            });
          };

          for (var j = 0; j < events.length; j++) {
            makeRequest(events[j]);
          }
        });
    });
    };
```

Please help me to fixed that code with `access_token` for avoiding authorization

Comment: Do you mean using a [service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account)? If not can you provide more information?

Comment: Kessy, let's say we have such a situation ..I am an ordinary user and I want to link my account from site with a google calendar. I created sync button, onClick that button google wants to know which google account he should link with. After choosing account in response I am getting access token and storing that in localStorage. Next I am going to my forms page in site and want to create new event ... but after creating google again wants to link with one of my accounts. Now I want understand how can avoid that accounts linking process?.... I only want to linked one time

Answer (score 1):

Access tokens expire after one hour.  Once the access token has expired you will need to authorize the user again order to have access to their data again.

Normally with Oauth2 you can request something called off line access this will then give you something called a refresh token. Refresh tokens for applications that are in production are long lived and for the most part do not expire.  You can use a refresh token to request an new access token when ever needed. This way you will not need to authorize the user after an hour.

Unfortunately refresh tokens are not supported by client sided authorization using JavaScript. You will need to switch to a server sided language.

If you are trying to access a static calendar account owned by you the developer as opposed to calendar accounts owned by your users you could use something called service accounts.  However service accounts only work with Google calendar if you use domain wide delegation to a google workspace account it will not work with standard Gmail calendar accounts.   Also service accounts are not supported by JavaScript you will need to switch to a server sided programming language.

After all that I hope you can see if you are sticking with JavaScript you will need to request authorization of your users when ever the access token expires.